# When Firebase analytic events are triggered?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, analytics

I am using firebase analytic events to get user event updates, but there is a scenario where I need the user info without been tapped on any button. So I tried but noting is getting displayed in xcode debug console. So do the firebase events gets called without user interaction like click on button Or dragged segment

Comment: What's stopping you from reading the doc?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseanalytics/api/reference/Categories

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger an Analytics event without any input from the user. You can put the event code in any function.

If you need the event to be triggered on page load, you can put the event triggering logic inside your `viewDidLoad()` function, or in any function really.

Here's the code to trigger a FirebaseAnalytics event.

```swift
import FirebaseAnalytics

Analytics.logEvent("MyEvent", parameters: [
    "parameter" : "parameter body"
])
```

Without knowing what kind of event you need to log, and with what criteria, it's hard to give a more precise answer to your question.

**Further resources**

- [Firebase docs regarding Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics)
- [How to trigger a FirebaseAnalytics event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=ios)
- [How to track Screenviews](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews) in case you are trying to track your screen views